# SendKeys not working on Firefox but working on chrome

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to build a scraping app using python and selenium and run it on a server. What it does is creating and scheduling posts on CreatorStudio to share them on Instagram. I can't use Chrome or Edge Chromium because I can't send emojis using `send_keys` on these browsers. Firefox on the other hand can send emojis. And I can't use copy-paste workaround because it's a server. `send_keys`works fine on Firefox when I am trying to send keys to an `input` web element e.g: google search bar. But when I try to send keys to this element `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = '_1mf _1mj']")`, It doesn't work on Firefox but it does on Chrome.

Is there any way to solve this issue?? Or is there any work arround or some java script I can run?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, try creating the element xpath using input tag. Otherwise you can use JavaScript Executor or Action class to send keys.

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').setAttribute('value', 'new value for element')");